# AWS Postgres instance hangs / timeouts for no good reason

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a database hosted at AWS RDS. The db was hosted for close to 3 years now and seemd to work without issues. Without any significant changes (besides writing new records in the DB), the connections to it started to hang/timeout. Sometimes a connection goes through but it takes about 30-60 seconds, and then the connection drops shortly after.

In the postgres error log, there is nothing particularly concerning. The most relevant thing I found is:

```
2022-11-15 14:08:11 UTC::@:[365]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2022-11-15 14:08:12 UTC::@:[365]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.277 s, sync=0.040 s, total=0.838 s; sync files=1, longest=0.040 s, average=0.040 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2022-11-15 14:10:37 UTC::@:[368]:WARNING: worker took too long to start; canceled
2022-11-15 14:10:52 UTC::@:[3350]:WARNING: autovacuum worker started without a worker entry
```

Running telnet to the DB seems to pass, and on the AWS dashboard I don't see anything particularly concerning - normal number of connections, CPU/mem usage.

I tried restarting the db instance, upgrading to a newer version of postgres, and restarting the clients, but to no avail.

Any ideas what I can look at, in order to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: For whatever reason, starting server processes takes a very long time. That explains both phenomena. Since it is a hosted database, you'll have to rely on Amazon's support for that. Good luck.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Forgive the ignorant question - it seems that for regular users there is only billing support. Is there support where you report any outages/server issues?

Comment: Perhaps not, I don't know. In that case you have managed to get locked in by a vendor that wants to take your money, but not provide any support. Congratulations. Perhaps you can pay extra money to get your questions answered.

Comment: Have you tried [Rebooting the DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RebootInstance.html) or [Monitoring Amazon RDS metrics with Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html) to see if there are any strange behaviours on the database (eg CPU spikes)?

Comment: AWS Support is optional. If you [subscribe to AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/pricing/) then you can contact them about problems, and ask questions about AWS services. This can be quite worthwhile when operating Production systems, but it is your choice whether you wish to spend the additional money for AWS Support.